# How can I declare a string within this method?

Tags: c#, .net, windows

I have a public string, called tester, that I would like to use within my deletetask_Click event, how could this be used within the st.DeleteTask line?

```
public string tester {get;set;}

private void deletetask_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ScheduledTasks st = new ScheduledTasks(@"\\" + System.Environment.MachineName);
    st.DeleteTask("tester");
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remove the quotes:

```
st.DeleteTask(tester);
```

Answer (score 3):

Unless I am misunderstanding your question, you can just try:

```
st.DeleteTask(tester); // no quotes around variable name
```

When you put quotes around it, you are essentially creating a new string which contains the text `"tester"`. However, when you remove the quotes, C# interprets it as a reference to the `tester` variable, which contains the string you already created.

Answer (score 2):

Couldn't you just pass the variable tester to the method st.DeleteTask?

Answer (score 0):

You can just use it as is.  In your code snippet, `tester` is class-level, and can be used in any of the classes non-static methods.

```
private void deletetask_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ScheduledTasks st = new ScheduledTasks(@"\\" + System.Environment.MachineName);
    st.DeleteTask(tester);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If tester is declared within the same class as that method, then simply like this:

```
private void deletetask_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ScheduledTasks st = new ScheduledTasks(@"\\" + System.Environment.MachineName);
    st.DeleteTask(tester);
}
```

If it's not, where is it declared?