# Problems with settings a string C#

Tags: c#, .net, windows

As far as I am aware the code below appears to do what I intend it to do - although for some reason the deletest string does not appear to be set properly, as when I click on the button the action does not happen. Although if I define the actual task name e.g. "task3" it deletes it.

Code:

```
public string deletest {get;set;}


private void deletetask_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string deletetask = DeleteTaskBox.Text;
    ScheduledTasks st = new ScheduledTasks(@"\\" + System.Environment.MachineName);
    st.DeleteTask(deletest);
}
```

Comment: Put a breakpoint in and verify the DeleteTaskbox.Text value is what you expect it to be.

Comment: Just an observation:  Are you the same person that wrote this question?  The code is nearly identical to your question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6429603/how-can-i-declare-a-string-within-this-method

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
string ***deletetask*** = DeleteTaskBox.Text;
ScheduledTasks st = new ScheduledTasks(@"\\" + System.Environment.MachineName);
st.DeleteTask(***deletest***);
```

Different variable names.

Answer (score 5):

You're passing null to the st.DeleteTask method.  deletest and deletetask are two different variables.

Answer (score 4):

Even if you didn't have the typo that the other answers have mentioned, you'd *still* have a bug - you wouldn't be setting the property, because you'd still be declaring a new local variable in the method. The call to `st.DeleteTask` would work, but nothing else would then be able to access it later. You *don't* want to declare a new variable. You want something like:

```
public string DeleteTaskName { get; set; }

private void deletetask_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Note that this doesn't declare a variable
    DeleteTaskName = DeleteTaskBox.Text;
    ScheduledTasks st = new ScheduledTasks(@"\\" + Environment.MachineName);
    st.DeleteTask(DeleteTaskName);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

is this what you were trying to do?

```
public string deletest {get;set;}

private void deletetask_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    deletest = DeleteTaskBox.Text;
    ScheduledTasks st = new ScheduledTasks(@"\\" + System.Environment.MachineName);
    st.DeleteTask(deletest);
}
```